# Bead of karma on character with multiple caster classes

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, caster-level

Let's say there's, for example, a cleric/wizard with a Karma bead, does this character get an CL increase on both his classes at the same time or must he chose a class on activaction?

Even though there's a requirement to cast divine spells in order to use the bead of Karma, it doesn't say the bonus works only for divine classes. Also the description of the bead says

> Wearer casts his spells at +4 caster level. Effect lasts 10 minutes.

With no restriction to a single caster class. Which leads to my doubt (or better, i want to make sure i'm getting it right)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the premium edition of the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2012) when a creature activates the *bead of karma* that's found on the standard or *greater strand of prayer beads*, for 10 min. the "[w]earer casts his spells at +4 caster level" (267).

Thus the increased caster level affects *any* spell the user casts, no matter what class the spell's from, and no matter if the spell's arcane or divine.

No more's said about the *bead* except that "the *bead*… *of karma* can be activated by any character capable of casting divine spells" (*ibid.*). This *is* disturbingly vague: ask the DM if this means that, for example, a rogue with 1 rank in the skill Use Magic Device and that has two *divine scrolls of cure light wounds*—one in each hand—is capable of casting divine spells. This DM would say *No*, but others may disagree. Similarly, it *seems* legit to this DM to allow a *strand*'s wearer to activate the *bead* then give the *strand*  to another creature to wear so that the other creature can benefit from the *bead*'s effect for its remaining duration without the other creature having activated the *bead*'s effect… but this DM can imagine other DMs taking issue with that.

Note that the *bead of karma* doesn't effectively raise the wearer's caster level *in general*: the *bead*'s effect occurs *only* when the wearer casts a spell, at which point that spell is cast at +4 caster level. Prior to casting a spell, the wearer's caster level is what it is normally, even if the *bead*'s effect is active.

Also note that the standard *strand of prayer beads'* price is changed by the premium edition *Dungeon Master's Guide* from [25,800 gp](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#strand-of-prayer-beads) (the price of a *bead of healing* plus a *bead of smiting* hence—without this change—allowing free standard *strands of prayer beads* on which are only *beads of karma*) to [45,800 gp](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#strandofPrayerBeads).